# How to split a java string at backslash and underscore

Tags: java

i have this string `config_wdiCore_20_2.xls`

I want to split this for having in output this result:

> module: wdiCore
>
> version: 20_2

***My Java:***

```
String XLS_PPT_FILE = "D:\\xxx\\Excel\\yyyy\\config_wdiCore_20_2.xls"
String[] path = XLS_PPT_FILE.split("\\\\");
String namePath = path[path.length-1];
println(namePath);
```

***Output:***

> config_wdiCore_20_2.xls

How can i split this output to have the coe module and the code version ?

***UPDATE:***

```
namePath.split("_")
```

*Ouptut:*
[image]

```
namePath.split("_", 3)
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidWallace yes so i don't have the good result for version because there used underscore

Comment: Did you try `namePath.split("_", 3)` ?

Comment: @jhamon it's look like the good solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`String.lastIndexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29) to get the last back-slash. Then strip off the extension ".xls" and finally split by `_` with a limit of 3 (so your version stays one `String`). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String XLS_PPT_FILE = "D:\\xxx\\Excel\\yyyy\\config_wdiCore_20_2.xls";
    int pos = XLS_PPT_FILE.lastIndexOf('\\');
    String baseName = (pos > -1) ? XLS_PPT_FILE.substring(pos + 1)
            : XLS_PPT_FILE;
    pos = baseName.indexOf(".xls");
    if (pos > -1) {
        baseName = baseName.substring(0, pos);
    }
    String[] parts = baseName.split("\\_", 3);
    System.out.printf("module: %s%nversion: %s%n", parts[1], parts[2]);
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
module: wdiCore
version: 20_2
```

Answer (score 2):

Split based on underscore that is not preceded by digit and dot and get the value from desired index.

```
(?<!\d)_|\.
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE2aT2/1)

Alternatively you can use [*Positive Lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of [*Negative Lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as well

```
(?<=\D)_|\.
```

output array:

```
[0] >  config 
[1] >  wdiCore 
[2] >  20_2 
[3] >  xls
```

---

Get the desired values from captured groups at index 1 and 2

```
([^_]*)_(\d+(_\d+)?)\.
```

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/cE2aT2/2)

Sample code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if(m.find()){
   String module = m.group(1);
   String version = m.group(2);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here, because it allows for any number of underscores in the portion of the filename that precedes the number.  However, on the first line, you should change "followed by" to "preceded by" - otherwise the explanation doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
namePath.split("_", 3)
```

Split the `namePath`string on the first 2 `_` characters (returning a list of 3 strings)